# Relationships with Django and rest framework add replace fields

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

My user object with rest framework has an `avatar_id` and a `cover_id`. But Instead of displaying that to the API, I want it to be the actual avatar URL and cover URL already.

My `User` model:

```
avatar_id = models.IntegerField()
cover_id = models.IntegerField()
```

My `UserAvatar` model:

```
id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
user_id = models.IntegerField()
file_id = models.IntegerField()
```

My `Files` model:

```
id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
filename = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

Same concept with `UserCover`.

How do I remove the `avatar_id` from the results of `/users/` and add a avatar field with the actual avatar filename?

Comment: 15 days later, could you answer if my answer helped you? And if it did, please vote and/or set as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your question correctly, but here what I think the problems are. Reading your question, I assumed that you are a beginner, so I answered as such. Sorry if it's not the case.

- You don't need to add the id fields, it's done automatically by Django because all tables need a primary key. You define a PK only when you need to name it something else than 'id'.
- You should really read the [Django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/intro/tutorial01/#creating-models) which explains how to define models. User.cover_id and UserAvatar.file_id should be defined as ForeignKey. If you don't know what a foreign key is, then stop playing with Django and read a database tutorial before.
- There's already a model and a set of classes to [manage your users](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/auth/) in Django. You should use them. For example, a "user profile" is the right way to [extend the user model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model).
- If you force the users to choose one avatar in a set of predefined avatars, then what you want to do is ok. If the users can choose any avatar (upload), then you should use [OneToOneField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/) or put it directly in the user model (or profile).

I don't know what is a `UserCover`, but here's what your models could look like:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    # Link to Django normal User (name, email, pass)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)

    # Any information that a user needs, like cover, wathever that is, age, sexe, etc.
    avatar = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

Or like this if a will be reused often :

```
class Avatar(models.Model):
    # name = ...
    # description = ...
    path = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
    avatar = models.ForeignKey(Avatar, unique=True)

    # other data
```