# name * is not defined in class Meta

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Due to the structure of the tables (see question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21066134/relationships-with-django-and-rest-framework-add-replace-fields)). I had to define the avatar as ManyToMany Through.

But it now returns an array of the avatar but the truth is, a user only has one avatar. So I tried to get only the first element of the array so it will only return 1 avatar but raises an error:

> name 'avatar' is not defined

if I do it like this:

```
class UsersSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  avatar = serializers.RelatedField(many=False)
  cover  = serializers.RelatedField(many=False)
  class Meta:
    model  = Users
    avatar = avatar[0] #this errors
    fields = ('id', 'username', 'email', 'first_name', 'middle_name', 'last_name', 'gender', 'birthdate', 'privacy', 'avatar', 'cover')
    read_only_fields = ('id', 'username')
```

Moving the `avatar = avatar[0]` to the upper class, does another error:

> 'RelatedField' object does not support indexing

Any idea on how to resolve this?

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1765677/python-nested-classes-scope

Comment: if user has only one avatar, maybe it's better to use [onetoone field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/fields/#onetoonefield)?